# Syntax coloring on unity visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

For some reason nearly everything is simply white, I'd prefer the more varying colors based on like, what kind of thing you are typing. I just recently started so I don't know the terminology. I see a lot of Unity tutorials that have coloring like that. Thanks!

I'm using a cs file

Comment: You probably mean *syntax highlighting*. Vistual Studio should have this on by default for source code files (with an appropriate file extension).

Answer (score 0):

I think what may work for u is this

[Inside Visual Studio - go to Tools and scroll to Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9wZG.png)

[Text Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF68T.png)

[C# and then Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBaYZ.png)

[and choose Visual Study 2019 under Editor Color Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0vYj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reload the project. In Solution Explorer it may state:

```
Assembly-CSharp (unloaded)
```

Right click this text and select **Reload Project** from the resulting context menu